# confusion while subtracting and post decrementing at once

Tags: c, operators, postfix-operator

I'm stuck in a question of decrement the code is as follows

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int x = 4, y = 3, z;
z = x-- - y;
printf("%d %d %d\n",x,y,z);

return 0;
}
```

according to what i know the output should be 4 3 0 
the explanation for the value of z according to me is as follows:
first as it's a post decrement so first we'll decrease the value of y from x i.e. 4-3 that's equal to 1 and according to me we'll again decrease 1 from this 1 (or we don't correct me if I'm wrong here) and the output will be 0.

Comment: `z` is `4-3`, then **`x`** gets decremented, not `z` (resulting in `3 3 1`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression `x--` evaluates to the *current* value of `x` which is 4.  The value of `y` is then subtracted from this value resulting in 1 which is what is assigned to `z`. 
`x` is then decremented as a side effect of the postdecrement.

So the output will be 3 3 1.

Answer (score 3):

From the C Standard (6.5.2.4 Postfix increment and decrement operators)

> 2 The result of the postfix ++ operator is the value of the operand.
>   **As a side effect, the value of the operand object is incremented (that
>   is, the value 1 of the appropriate type is added to it)**. See the
>   discussions of additive operators and compound assignment for
>   information on constraints, types, and conversions and the effects of
>   operations on pointers. **The value computation of the result is
>   sequenced before the side effect of updating the stored value of the
>   operand**. With respect to an indeterminately-sequenced function call,
>   the operation of postfix ++ is a single evaluation. Postfix ++ on an
>   object with atomic type is a read-modify-write operation with
>   memory_order_seq_cst memory order semantics.98)
>
> 3 The postfix -- operator is analogous to the postfix ++ operator,
>   except that the value of the operand is decremented (that is, the
>   value 1 of the appropriate type is subtracted from it).

Thus in this statement

```
z = x-- - y;
```

there is used the value of the variable x before the decrement that is 4. So `4 - 3` yields `1`.

But the object x itself was decremented and after this statement its value becomes equal to 3.

So as result you will get the following output

```
3 3 1
```

By the way you may rewrite this statement

```
z = x-- - y;
```

like :)

```
z = x --- y;
```

Comment: "`z = x --- y;`" — please shoot me :D